# Unable to add slot and connect it to a button

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I gathered a code of an application called calendar from the base of examples of the Qt Framework. I am trying to learn from it and add there some functionality. The problem right now that I've got is that I want to implement  two function to the two button that I created ( one for increase counting of the days and the second  for decrease ).

**The code that I added to the function for increasing the days is:**

```
void MainWindow::forward(int *click_forward)
{
    click_forward++;
}
```

**and the code added to the function for decreasing the days:**

```
void MainWindow::backwards(int *click_backwards)
{
    click_backwards--; 
}
```

In the constructor I defined a variable named click which of the int
   type, and I sent this variable to the both function by reference:

```
   forward(&click);
   backward(&click);
```

In the header file, in the public slosts area these both functions are
  defined as:

```
   void forward(int *click_forward);

   void backwards(int *click_backwards);
```

I also implemented two SIGNAL-SLOT connections:

```
   QObject::connect(nextbtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(forward(int  
   &click)));

   QObject::connect(beforebtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, 
   SLOT(backwards(int &clickt)));
```

But for some reasons when I compile the project I receive an information that:

```
   QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::forward(int &click) 

   QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::backwards(int &clickt)
```

I wanted to use pointers in these two functions, just to work on the original variable itself not on the copy.
Could I please ask you to point me out what I am doing wrong.

Thank you,

Comment: Hello, signals and slots need to have the same signature. Furthermore, I am sure you rather mean (*click_forward)++;
If you want to use a slot in this way, create an intermediate object maintaining the click-counter.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your signal and slot(s) have different signatures: signal has no arguments, but slot has an argument of pointer type. Besides, even if your signals connections would work, the execution of such code wouldn't do anything useful (at least) as you modify the temporary defined variables `click_backwards` etc.

I would solve this in the following way:

Define the class member variables and slots:

```
class MainWindow
{
    [..]
private slots:
    void forward();
    void backwards();

private:
    int click_forward;
    int click_backwards;
}
```

Define slots:

```
void MainWindow::forward()
{
    click_forward++;
}

void MainWindow::backwards()
{
    click_backwards--; 
}
```

And finally establish connections:

```
QObject::connect(nextbtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(forward()));
QObject::connect(beforebtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(backwards()));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but there is also another issue, due to when I tried to use your solution and compiled the program, I recevied:  no matching function for call to MainWindow::forward(int*) as I recalled function this way in the constructor - forward(&click); so in the function itself there should be probably this variable 'click' received. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Both `forward()` and `backwards()` functions do not have any argument. You need just call them without arguments too.

Comment: But shouldn't both of them have got any argument in a moment when they are receiving an adress of the variable passed to these functions through the reference in the constructor: int click; forward(&click); backwards(&click) ?

Comment: I am asking because right now I removed the arguments from these functions, which right now they are as: void MainWindow::forward(){(*click_forward)++;}   void MainWindow::backwards(){        (*click_backwards)--;} and in the header the definition of these functions right now is: void forward(); void backwards();

Comment: and while compiling I receive an error like: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::forward(int*)'

Answer (score 1):

if you do your signals and slots like this, then you get a compiler error instead of a run time error, which i personally find very helpful since it will just tell you that they wont connect because of incompatible signals/slots

```
QObject::connect(nextbtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::forward);
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way, you're not increasing the value of the integer, you're increasing the pointer.

That's a bug waiting to happen.

Comment: Just to clarify, do this: `(*click_forward)++` instead of this: `click_forward++`.  Same with `click_backwards--`.

Comment: hopefully he has allocated the ints and isn't just poking around random memory....